# compiler optimisation

Tags: c++, optimization

I just learned that the compiler cleverly replaces calls to functions and variables by essentially replacing them with the code they represent. With this in mind would the second method in fact be better below (due to clarity) and in fact run just as fast as the first one?

```
//check to see if sphere intersects the box
bool BoundingBox::Intersects(BoundingSphere boundingSphere)
{
// check for intersection on each axis by seeing if the radius is large enough to reach the edge of the cube on the 
// appropriate side. All must evaluate to true for there to be an intersection.
return (
    ((boundingSphere.Centre().x < negCorner.x && boundingSphere.Radius() > posCorner.x - boundingSphere.Centre().x) ||
     (boundingSphere.Centre().x > posCorner.x && boundingSphere.Radius() > boundingSphere.Centre().x - negCorner.x)) 
     &&
    ((boundingSphere.Centre().y < negCorner.y && boundingSphere.Radius() > posCorner.y - boundingSphere.Centre().y) ||
     (boundingSphere.Centre().y > posCorner.y && boundingSphere.Radius() > boundingSphere.Centre().y - negCorner.y)) 
     &&
    ((boundingSphere.Centre().z < negCorner.z && boundingSphere.Radius() > posCorner.z - boundingSphere.Centre().z) ||
     (boundingSphere.Centre().z > posCorner.z && boundingSphere.Radius() > boundingSphere.Centre().z - negCorner.z)));
}
```

Second Method:

```
//check to see if sphere intersects the box
bool BoundingBox::Intersects(BoundingSphere boundingSphere)
{
bool xIntersects, yIntersect, zIntersects;

xIntersects = 
    ((boundingSphere.Centre().x < negCorner.x && boundingSphere.Radius() > posCorner.x - boundingSphere.Centre().x) ||
     (boundingSphere.Centre().x > posCorner.x && boundingSphere.Radius() > boundingSphere.Centre().x - negCorner.x)));

yIntersects =   
            ((boundingSphere.Centre().y < negCorner.y && boundingSphere.Radius() > posCorner.y - boundingSphere.Centre().y) ||
     (boundingSphere.Centre().y > posCorner.y && boundingSphere.Radius() > boundingSphere.Centre().y - negCorner.y)));

zIntersects = 
            ((boundingSphere.Centre().z < negCorner.z && boundingSphere.Radius() > posCorner.z - boundingSphere.Centre().z) ||
     (boundingSphere.Centre().z > posCorner.z && boundingSphere.Radius() > boundingSphere.Centre().z - negCorner.z)));

return (xIntersects && yIntersects && zIntersects);
}
```

Comment: perhaps this is not the best example as they are both relatively similar, but the idea is that the second one is clearer but uses more lines.

Comment: To some degree it depends on the compiler you are using and how well it optimises code :)

Comment: This is more about readability then optimization.

Comment: AGree with Philip. The biggest improvement would be the introduction of `Point Centre = boundingSphere.Centre(); int Radius = boundingSphere.Radius();`. I also suspect the code is wrong; the boundingSphere seems quite square.

Comment: ah, so calling another object like that uses more memory? Also, why do you think it is square?

Comment: To me, they are both equally beautiful :) And the keyword you are looking for is `inlining`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this is not an accurate sphere vs. box check. It's essentially a broken (it won't report an intersection when the sphere center is contained in the box!) box vs. box-around-a-sphere test . Look for Arvo's algorithm if you want to do this right.

But back to your question: if there's measurable speed difference, and I doubt there is, it most certainly wouldn't be related to as much to inlining, but to the slightly different semantics of the two functions. The first function does lazy evaluation on its top-level via the `&&` operator. So if you get a negative result on the first axis, it'll bump out and not test the other ones. This will likely give you a speed advantage on a very slow computer when you have enough negative results on that axis or the second.

The second function will not check whether you got a negative answer on a prior axis. As a result, it'll always test all three. Now this will probably be faster on a decent computer, since it doesn't have to wait for the results of the first checks to figure out whether it may execute the checks that are coming next. So this has less branch-mispredictions in general, which is often faster than just doing the work of both branches.

Then again, the optimizer might me smart enough to figure out that it can execute the expressions on the other side of the `&&` operator without side-effects. Inlining (either explicitly or via link-time code-generation) actually plays a small role here - as the optimizer needs to look at what the `Centre` and `Radius` functions actually do.

But the only sure way to know is look at the generated code and benchmark it!

Answer (score 8):

There is no guarantee of your expected behaviour - the compiler would have to be pretty smart to work out that it did not have to calculate **all** the conditions for x/y/z before returning a result.

In the first version you KNOW you will return on the first failed test.  I'd stick with that, and comment and format the code to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue a combinations of the two. You want to check `xIntersects && yIntersects && z Intersects`, so make them each their own functions. Like so:

```
bool BoundingBox::Intersects(BoundingSphere boundingSphere)
{
  return XIntersects(boundingSphere) && YIntersects(boundingSphere) && ZIntersects(boundingSphere);
}

bool BoundingBox::XIntersects(BoundingSphere boundingSphere)
{
  return ((boundingSphere.Centre().x < negCorner.x && boundingSphere.Radius() > posCorner.x - boundingSphere.Centre().x) ||
          (boundingSphere.Centre().x > posCorner.x && boundingSphere.Radius() > boundingSphere.Centre().x - negCorner.x));
}
bool BoundingBox::YIntersects(BoundingSphere boundingSphere)
{
  return ((boundingSphere.Centre().y < negCorner.y && boundingSphere.Radius() > posCorner.y - boundingSphere.Centre().y) ||
          (boundingSphere.Centre().y > posCorner.y && boundingSphere.Radius() > boundingSphere.Centre().y - negCorner.y));
}
bool BoundingBox::ZIntersects(BoundingSphere boundingSphere)
{
  return ((boundingSphere.Centre().z < negCorner.z && boundingSphere.Radius() > posCorner.z - boundingSphere.Centre().z) ||
          (boundingSphere.Centre().z > posCorner.z && boundingSphere.Radius() > boundingSphere.Centre().z - negCorner.z));
}
```

You get both the speed of the first and the clarity of the second, and an optimizing compiler might even optimize out the function calls.